# Android MediaPlayer Runtime Error

Tags: java, android

With this code I want to play a sound. I call the playSound() method for it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private MediaPlayer cPiano;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
}
public void playSound(){
    cPiano = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cpiano);
    cPiano.start();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView
{
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder; 
private MainActivity mainActivity

public GameView(Context context)
{
    super(context); 
    mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    }

    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    for (Pixel pixel : pixelList)
    {
        pixel.onDraw(canvas); 
    }
    for (int i = pixelList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Pixel pixel = pixelList.get(i);
        if (pixel.isBar())
        {
            mainActivity.playSound();
            removePixel(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is only the most important code. But when it should play the sound I get an Android Runtime Error

What is wrong?

Comment: remove this `mainActivity = new MainActivity()` you can start your media player in gameview since you have the activity context.

Comment: Okay but I still get the error. LogCat says that the onDraw() makes trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mainActivity.playSound() line try:

```
MainActivity host = (MainActivity)getContext();
host.playSound();
```

Also remove new MainActivity(). An activity must NOT be directly instantiated